# How to add shadow to linearlayout with a shape?

Tags: android

I create a linearlayout and a triangle shape how to add shadow to it?
[image]

sorry for the drawing
it is a rounded corner rect with a down triangle.

how to add shadow surround it?
I mean surround it that the left and right of the triangle is alpha.
and the shadow is spread  like linear-gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Add this file in your drawable

shadow.xml

```
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB"/>
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

then set it in your layout and update as you want.